How to debug a module that is imported using a notebook file in VSCode
I've built a utilities.py script to hold functions that I need to regularly perform on a dataset. It is largely in pandas.
I then have a notebook, call it process.ipynb, that imports the script with import utilities as ut. So far so good.
I've got a step in the process that I know I want to fix but I want to see what a variable containing a dataframe looks like.
The instructions should be simple:

Click to set the red breakpoint function in the script where I want the code to stop.
Go to the notebook and in the cell that runs the code and click the left hand side of the cell and click 'debug cell'.
Code runs

And in system output I get
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.

So far, so good.
The code reaches breakpoint and I think I can interrogate variables.
Nothing shows in the variables window.

I've tried dir() but I don't recognise any variables, and similarly unrecognise outputs from locals()
I've typed mgd, the name of the variable, and print(mgd) but get the response:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'mgd' is not defined

I'm keen to avoid using print statements where possible but this is confusing. What's the next step?
I got asked for a launch.json file. I used.
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}

EDIT: my example.
data_demo.py
import pandas as pd

class City:
    def __init__(self, df=pd.DataFrame()):
        self.df = df

    def transform_city(self):
        print('Transforming city data...')
        df = self.df.T

        return df

notebook.
import pandas as pd
import data_demo as dd

data = {
    'Name': ['John', 'Anna', 'Peter', 'Linda'],
    'Age': [28, 34, 29, 32],
    'City': ['New York', 'Paris', 'Berlin', 'London']
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Initialize the City class with the DataFrame
city_instance = dd.City(df)

# Now, call the transform_city method
transformed_city = city_instance.transform_city()

# You can put a breakpoint on the line below in VS Code
print(transformed_city)

I've put the red dot breakpoint on the line in the script
 df = self.df.T

Debug console:
df
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'df' is not defined


Please make a [mre] with example code for the module and notebook.

@wjandrea I've tried. I'll update in a minute or so

Oh, OK! When you break at a line, it hasn't executed yet. Step over it and then check the value.

Beside the point, but data_demo doesn't actually need to import pandas for this example. You can just make df not have a default. And on the other hand, if you do use pd.DataFrame() as a default, be aware that it's mutable.
